# Multiple View Layout Framework7 Hybrid Application

Tags: javascript, mobile, hybrid, html-framework-7

I have 2 different layouts. One for before login and one more for after login.

I already read the instructions here. http://framework7.io/docs/views.html

And still cant understand why my apps become like this:

[image: Middle part of this application]

It display 2 views at once. Can scroll fully throught both views.

This is the js involved:

```
var mainView = myApp.addView('.view-main');
var anotherView = myApp.addView('.another-view');

//to call anotherView after login
mainView.router.load(anotherView);
```

Answer (score 1):

Each view is simply a div with its own content and its own history. So, just use them as divs:

```
var mainView = myApp.addView('.view-main');
var anotherView = myApp.addView('.another-view');
//init your application somwhere here
$$('.another-view').hide(); //hide view that after login
//do somethig and login
$$('.view-main').hide(); //hide view that before login
$$('.another-view').show(); //show wiew that after login
```

Of course, this is very strange way to use views but i hope you know what you doing. Please, read documentation again.

Comment: Hi, Teo! Could you provide an example of a better approach to the problem?

Comment: Man, You are such a optimist!) Last time i use this framework more than year ago an it was not my code, i wrote it under NDA.

Comment: OK, let's try explain more detailed.
Any view in Framework7 is a div element. Without any other styles or scripts it will be placed at page as any other div. Difference is that view can load pages into it and store its own history.
You can show and hide them in the same way as other divs. Code in example just using framework methods instead of pure js:
    $$('.view-main') //get the main view by its class .view-main
      .hide(); // and make it invisible
   $$('.another-view')  // get another view
      .show(); //and make it visible

Comment: You dont need views itself, i suppouse, you ned a navigation between your pages. If so, use framework7 router to load another code template or file https://framework7.io/docs/router-api.html.
Good luck.